# Random sets with three random numbers in it (sampling random points in a cube)

Tags: r, random

Each point inside a cube has three values (X, Y & Z axes). There are in-built functions in `R`,  pertaining to the generation of sets with single random number (one number per observation), such as `runif()`, `sample()`, `rnorm()`, `set.seed()` etc. Thinking in a similar logic, the numbers are generated in a single axis, with those functions.

My question is:

- Is there any function to generate random sets with three random numbers in it (or generalising, random sets with more than one number per observation)?
- What should be the approach, if the answer is no for the former?

Comment: Can't you just generate three random numbers independently? I assume the points would be evenly distributed inside the cube. `list(x=runif(10), y=runif(10), z=runif(10))`

Comment: @[MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick), yeah, that would be the thought at first! But I guess @[Julius Vainora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320535/julius-vainora) had to the point & elegant solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the case of cubes, `runif` is perfectly flexible to achieve all that. In particular, we can specify the number of points to be generated, and for each axis we may also specify a different range. For instance,

```
lower <- c(0, 10, 20)
upper <- c(1, 11, 21)
n <- 5
matrix(runif(n * 3, lower, upper), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
#            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 0.03372777 10.99940 20.03487
# [2,] 0.33839128 10.91506 20.61724
# [3,] 0.28628535 10.73780 20.83405
# [4,] 0.31427078 10.49257 20.69737
# [5,] 0.64146235 10.64392 20.97785
```

The same would hold for `rnorm`, `rbeta`, etc.

Thinking about this differently, you want to sample from a *multivariate* distribution, where perhaps we even have some dependence. For that there also are functions, such as `?mvrnorm` in the `MASS` package or `?rdirichlet` in `MCMCpack`. However, when dealing, say, with points distributed uniformly in a cube, following the approach above is standard and, if there is a need, you may define a corresponding function for the multivariate uniform distribution with independent components.

Comment: Thanks [Julius Vainora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320535/julius-vainora), for your crisp and insightful answer :) Didn't think it could be so easy! I love `R`